# pan buttons + jump to location in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4, data-visualization

I am creating a PyQt applicaton with a matplotlib figure containing 4 subplots (screenshot of the figure):
[image]
I would like to create 2 buttons "pan left" and "pan right", which will pan the 4 subplots at a selected rate on the x axis.
I would also like to include a button in the GUI - "jump to location", which will read a value from a textbox in the GUI and jump to that location on the x axis - on all 4 subplots.
I haven't found a way to manipulate the existing pan feature in these ways.
Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to manipulate the pan feature or create a new button for panning? What exactly is the problem you face?

Comment: I want to create new features, I just thought using the functionality that already exists in the pan feature would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

OK,
I ended up using a much simpler solution than I thought I would.
attached here is the code to my solution:

```
def jump_to_loc(self):
    global dataArrays
    for j in range(len(dataArrays)):
        ax = self.figure.axes[j]
        yBoundary = self.figure.yBoundaries[j]
        ax.axis([self.jmpToLocSpinner.value(), self.jmpToLocSpinner.value()+100, yBoundary[0], yBoundary[1]])
    self.figure.draw()

def pan(self, dir):
    global dataArrays
    dir_val = 0
    if dir == 'left':
        dir_val = 10
    else:
        dir_val = -10
    for j in range(len(dataArrays)):
        ax = self.figure.axes[j]
        yBoundary = self.figure.yBoundaries[j]
        x_axis = ax.get_xlim()
        ax.axis([x_axis[0] + dir_val, x_axis[1] + dir_val, yBoundary[0], yBoundary[1]])
    self.figure.draw()

def pan_left(self):
    self.pan('right')

def pan_right(self):
    self.pan('left')
```

I am basically utilizing the 'axis' function in the axes component, in order to set the x axis limits.

Comment: It's 4 years late, but for the readers: be careful about your variable names so that you do not unintentionally override Python's built-ins. "dir" is one of those. You can find a list here https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html <3 happy travels!